# Flight seating: Python (reset seating problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working on an assignment that books seats on a flight, the code I have so far works for everything besides the part for resetting all the seats to available when the flight is fully booked.

```
NUM_ROWS = 2
NUM_COLS = 1
AVAIL = '-'
BOOKED = 'X'

seatTable = []
for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
    column = []
    for j in range(NUM_COLS):
        column.append(AVAIL)
    seatTable.append(column)

def resetTable(seats):          ##<--need to fix
    seatTable = []
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
        column = []
        for j in range(NUM_COLS):
            column.append(AVAIL)
        seatTable.append(column)
    resetTable(printTable(seatTable))   ##<-- not correct
    print()

def printTable(seats):
    i=1
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    print('Row', end=' ')

    for num in range(NUM_COLS):
        print(f'{alpha[num]:2s}'.format(alpha),end='')
    print()

    for num in seats:
        print(f'{str(i):3s}'.format(str(i)), end=' ')
        i+=1
        for j in num:
            print(j,end=' ')
        print()

def full(seats):
    for row in seats:
        for seat in row:
            if seat == AVAIL:
                return False
    return True

def getRes():
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    while True:
        try:
            rowNum = input(f'Enter a row number (1 to {NUM_ROWS}): ')
            seatLetter = input(f'Enter a seat letter (A to {(alpha[NUM_COLS-1]).upper()}): ')
            reserve(seatTable,rowNum,seatLetter)
            break
        except:
            pass
        print('Error, Please choose another seat')
    print(f'Seat {rowNum}{seatLetter.upper()} has been booked\n')

def reserve(seats,resR,resC):
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    column = 0
    p = 0
    for i in alpha:
        if i.lower() == resC.lower():
            column = p
        p+=1
    row = int(resR)-1
    seats[row][column] = BOOKED

def main():
    printTable(seatTable)
    while not full(seatTable):
        getRes()
        printTable(seatTable)
    print('Plane is booked')
    next = input('\nWould you like to check the next flight? (Y/N): ')
    if next == 'y':                        ##<---problem 
        resetTable(printTable(seatTable))
        return main()
    else:
        exit()
main()
```

When I run the code to check for the "next flight" the seats reset, but then gets stuck on an infinite loop, followed by an error:

```
line 23, in resetTable
     resetTable(printTable(seatTable)) ##<-- not correct
     [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I fix the `resetTable()` function to work?

Comment: can you explain what `resetTable()` does

Comment: _How can I fix the resetTable() function to work?_ That's quite broad, have you done any debugging? I recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @RajuKomati it resets all of the seats on the plane to available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
NUM_ROWS = 2
NUM_COLS = 1
AVAIL = '-'
BOOKED = 'X'

seatTable = []
for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
    column = []
    for j in range(NUM_COLS):
        column.append(AVAIL)
    seatTable.append(column)

def resetTable(seats): 
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
        column = []
        for j in range(NUM_COLS):
            seatTable[i][j] = AVAIL

def printTable(seats):
    i=1
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    print('Row', end=' ')

    for num in range(NUM_COLS):
        print(f'{alpha[num]:2s}'.format(alpha),end='')
    print()

    for num in seats:
        print(f'{str(i):3s}'.format(str(i)), end=' ')
        i+=1
        for j in num:
            print(j,end=' ')
        print()

def full(seats):
    for row in seats:
        for seat in row:
            if seat == AVAIL:
                return False
    return True

def getRes():
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    while True:
        try:
            rowNum = input(f'Enter a row number (1 to {NUM_ROWS}): ')
            seatLetter = input(f'Enter a seat letter (A to {(alpha[NUM_COLS-1]).upper()}): ')
            reserve(seatTable,rowNum,seatLetter)
            break
        except:
            pass
        print('Error, Please choose another seat')
    print(f'Seat {rowNum}{seatLetter.upper()} has been booked\n')

def reserve(seats,resR,resC):
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    column = 0
    p = 0
    for i in alpha:
        if i.lower() == resC.lower():
            column = p
        p+=1
    row = int(resR)-1
    seats[row][column] = BOOKED

def main():
    printTable(seatTable)
    while not full(seatTable):
        getRes()
        printTable(seatTable)
    print('Plane is booked')
    next = input('\nWould you like to check the next flight? (Y/N): ')
    if next == 'y': 
        resetTable(seatTable)
        return main()
    else:
        exit()
main()
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!